# Ignoring mask while recording simulator screen

Tags: ios-simulator, xcrun, simctl

I'm trying to record a video of the simulator screen using the following command:

```sh
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo --mask=ignored ~/Desktop/footage.mp4
```

As you can see, I specified the value `ignored` for the `mask` parameter because I want to omit the mask on the iPhone X's simulator.

The documentation says:

> For non-rectantular displays, handle the mask by policy:
>   ignored: The mask is ignored and the unmasked framebuffer is saved.
>   black: The mask is rendered black.

---

Here is the result:

[image]

**As you can see, as soon as I start interacting with the simulator, the mask appears.**

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known bug?

PS: recording from an actual iPhone X is not a solution as I don't own such a device.

Comment: This is probably a bug. Can you file a radar at https://bugreport.apple.com and include the video?

Comment: @russbishop Done! (ref: 45643156 if it may helps)

Comment: This is a bug. When views change the mask is applied to video without respect. Did you, by any chance, find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, I filled a radar which was marked as duplicate. No workaround as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

While very far from an ideal solution, it might be possible for you to use an adjusted version of the 5.5 inch iPhone App Preview video. The 5.5 inch phones use 1920x1080 so what I had to do was basically squish one dimension to make the video 1920x886 pixels. Of course, it will look slightly squished, but it isn't that noticeable since it is only a reduction of around 20%. I would argue it is better than no App Preview or going through tonnes of trouble trying to borrow an iPhone X series device. At least until the simctl bug gets fixed!